# Rotativa(PDF) No me muestra las imágenes.(MVC)

Tags: html, css, html5, asp.net-mvc

Lo que sucede es que estoy realizando una aplicación web con asp.net mvc para generar certificados laborales, en fin que ya tengo todo menos descargar el pdf. use rotativa para descargar la vista y todo genial, pero cuando subí el proyecto en iis a la hora de descargar el mismo documento las imágenes no me aparecen. ya no que se hacer.

Comment: Desde el servidor que aloja a tu aplicación sobre IIS, tenés acceso a la imagen, por ejemplo la https://fotos.subefotos.com/c0ad7a4a2ba264c95e805ebaf848824co.png? Si ingresas por el navegador la podés visualizar correctamente?

Comment: Repito mi pregunta, desde el servidor accedes a las url de las imagenes de manera correcta mediante un navegador? Esto es para probar que un firewall no te esté cortando la salida hacia el host donde están alojadas las imágenes.

Comment: Hola, Indica por favor en la pregunta la Acción del Controlador donde generas el PDF, o sea,  donde tienes el `return new ViewAsPdf()`. Otra cosa, has probado a devolver simplemente la Vista HTML (`return View()`) a ver si te muestra las imágenes?.

Comment: si, ya probé retornar la vista y cargan las imágenes pero cuando uso rotativa para retornarla como pdf me quita las imágenes pero solo cuando lo cargo en el servidor iis. cuando compilo  ejecuto si me carga todo normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchas gracias a los que intentaron ayudarme logre resolverlo, anexo la respuesta por si en algún momento otra persona tiene esta misma duda.
escogí  por descargar la imagen y guardarla en el proyecto pero nada.

descubrí que  solo tuve que agregarle @Server.MapPath a la ruta de la imagen. y listo.

Comment: Por favor, marca tu respuesta como aceptada :)

Comment: gracias, es la primera vez que formulo una pregunta aqui

Comment: como se utiliza @Server.MapPath en la ruta